# total_words must be provided alongside corpus_file argument

Tags: gensim

I am training doc2vec with corpus file, which is very huge.

```
model = Doc2Vec(dm=1, vector_size=200, workers=cores, comment='d2v_model_unigram_dbow_200_v1.0')
model.build_vocab(corpus_file=path)
model.train(corpus_file=path, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)
```

I want to know how to get value of total_words.

Edit:

```
total_words=model.corpus_total_words
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the current (gensim 3.8.1, October 2019) [`Doc2Vec.train()` documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec.train), you shouldn't need to supply both `total_examples` and `total_words`, only one or the other:

> To support linear learning-rate decay from (initial) alpha to
>   min_alpha, and accurate progress-percentage logging, either
>   total_examples (count of documents) or total_words (count of raw words
>   in documents) MUST be provided. If documents is the same corpus that
>   was provided to build_vocab() earlier, you can simply use
>   total_examples=self.corpus_count.

But, it turns out the new `corpus_file` option does require both, and the doc-comment is wrong. I've filed [a bug](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2665) to fix this documentation oversight.

Yes, the model caches the number of words observed during the most-recent `build_vocab()` inside `model.corpus_total_words`, so `total_words=model.corpus_total_words` should do the right thing for you.

When using the `corpus_file` space-delimited text input option, then the numbers given by `corpus_count` and `corpus_total_words` should match the line- and word- counts you'd also see by running `wc your_file_path` at a command-line.

(If you were using the classic, plain Python iterable corpus option (which can't use threads as effetively), then there would be no benefit to supplying both `total_examples` and `total_words` to `train()` – it would only use one or the other for estimating progress.)

Comment: Good answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to stream documents while taking advantage of the multi-threading capabilities of passing in documents as a `corpus_file`? For training on many millions of documents (sentences) passing them in as a `corpus_file`, I am exceeding my memory limitations

Comment: Since `corpus_file` only reads files line-by-line, into many parallel threads, it'd be surprising if it were hitting memory problems. You should ask a separate question, with details of your setup and the error(s) you're hitting - hard to guess what your hitting, or see any relation to this other answer, in these tiny comments.